# Освобождение памяти void* var

Tags: c++, указатели

Задача - сделать класс, имеющий переменную, тип которой может выбираться пользователем самостоятельно. Как в деструкторе освободить выделенную память?

```
class UC{
private:
    void *var;
    ...
public:
    template<typename T>
    UC(const T& tmp){
        var = new T;
        (*(T*)var) = tmp;
    }
    ~UC();                // ?
    ...
};
```

Comment: а зачем хранить в `void*`? это же приватная часть. Храните в `T*`. А кому нужен void - просто отдавайте getter'ом. И все проблемы уйдут сами.

Comment: @KoVadim Тогда нужно делать класс шаблоном. Может автор хочет что-то типа `std::any`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это сильно напоминает `std::any`.

Вам нужно в каждом объекте хранить указатель на функцию, которая будет удалять ваш указатель, предварительно скастовав его к `T *`.

А выбирать правильную функцию нужно в шаблонном конструкторе.

Вот так:

```
class UC
{
  private:
    void *var;
    void (*del_func)(void*);

  public:
    template <typename T> UC(const T& tmp)
    {
        var = new T(tmp);
        del_func = [](void *p){delete static_cast<T*>(p);};
    }

    ~UC()
    {
        del_func(var);
    }
};
```

Я заменил `var = new T; (*(T*)var) = tmp;` на `var = new T(tmp);`. Так проще.

---

Кроме того, очень советую почитать про [***the rule of three***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Answer (score 0):

Наверно я показываю плохой способ, но возможно обойтись вообще без явного деструктора :)
Если использовать класс `shared_ptr` из STL:

```
class UC
{
private:
    shared_ptr<void> var;
public:
    template<typename T>
    UC(const T& tmp) : var { new T { tmp }, [](T * v) { delete v; } }
    { }

    void * getVar()
    { return var.get(); }
};

int main()
{
    string s { "test" };
    UC test { s };
    void * z = test.getVar();
    cout << *((string *)(z)) << endl;
}
```

P.S.:
вообще-то `shared_ptr` предназначен не для этого, но уж очень хорошо его функционал подходит :)